# "^" symbol not working properly on my batch file

Tags: batch

So I've created a batch file, but every time I get the error "Unbalanced Parenthesis."

```
@echo off
:top
cls
echo.
echo =========================
echo + -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=- +
echo =========================
echo.
echo.
set /p X=Insert drop chance (1 percent = 1, 5 percent = 5):
echo.
set /p Y=Insert attempt count:
echo.
echo.
echo.
set /A A=(X / 100)
set /A B=(Y / 100)
set /A Q=(( 1 - ( 1 - A ^ B )) * 100)
echo ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo (1 - ((1 - (DROP CHANCE %X% / 100)) ^ (ATTEMPTS %Y% / 100) * 100 = %Q%
echo ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo.
echo 1 for copy, 2 for reset, 3 to close.
@CHOICE /C:123
IF ERRORLEVEL 3 EXIT
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 GOTO top
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO copy
echo.
:copy
echo %Q% | clip
pause
goto :top
```

Error is at the "/A Q=(( 1 - ( 1 - A ^ B )) * 100)"

Please help, I'm extremely confused why it's not working.

Comment: In addition to your `^` problem: batch file arithmetic is integer-only.  If `X` is a percentage value (< 100), then `A=(X / 100)` will be 0.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the `^` sign. As an operator it is [bitwise-XOR](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_math.php) (and not `to the power of`) or a [line-continuation or escape symbol](http://www.psteiner.com/2008/12/using-caret-in-windows-batch-files.html).

You can fix the offending line as follows:

```
set /A "Q=(( 1 - ( 1 - A ^ B )) * 100)"
```

or:

```
set /A Q=(( 1 - ( 1 - A ^^ B )) * 100)
```

From your formula I think your are looking for the `exponent` function and not `bitwise-XOR`. This function is not available in Windows batch files, but there is a workaround [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5253356/does-a-power-to-function-in-batch-files-exist-exponent)